# How to can run bash shell on another server using php

Tags: php, ssh

I've a problem and hope you can help to me.

I have three servers (server1, server2, server3). Server1 is webserver, Server2 is gateway server to connect server3, Server3 is new servers.

I wanna from server1 ssh to server2 and server2 ssh to server3 via using PHP (have  username/password) and run bash shell from server1 on server3.

I don't have any ideal or solution to resolve this problem. Can you help me?

Answer (score -1):

did you try ssh2 by ssh_connect

Comment: I'm a newbie PHP. Can you demo? Thanks.